# Are questions on authors' personalities and/or recent activities on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I was curious about two topics: why is Bill Watterson so reclusive and what's he been doing for the last 20 years since he stopped writing *Calvin and Hobbes*? Are those appropriate questions for this site (since they're questions about an author) or would they be considered too speculative, too opinion-based and/or too broad?

Comment: Related previous questions: [Are questions about authors on-topic?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/151/17), [Are questions about author's personal opinions on-topic?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/543/17), [Are trivia questions about authors on-topic?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/801/17)